# Erlang outdir flag in "compile" module attribute

Tags: module, erlang

I know that to set the outdir from Erlang shell I need to do somethig like this:

```
c(some_module, [{outdir, "./beams"}]).
```

It works fine but now I want to set the outdir from the module using module attribute `-compile`. I'm doing:

```
-module(some_module).
-compile([export_all, {outdir, "./beams"}]).

%% here goes functions
```

But it doesn't work: folder "./beams is empty, but `export_all` flag is working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if this is correct syntax. What is sure, it works with Emakefile:

```
{'src/*', [{outdir, "ebin"},
       {i,"include"},
       debug_info,
       strict_record_tests,
       netload]}.
```

mantain following directory tree:

```
.
├── Emakefile
├── ebin
├── include
└── src
```

and use:

```
erl -make
```

It will place beams in ebin.

What I recommend in general is switching to [Rebar](https://github.com/basho/rebar). It will do all for you, and make the package compatible with erlang deployment policy.